# Location is not defined - NextJS 13 + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to created protected routes by going to my protected pages and making sure that the page can only be visible to users that have logged in. I've setup AuthProvider using Firebase and everything works fine just getting this error when I try to visit the protected routes whilst logged out and get redirected to the 'signin' page.

**The error I'm getting:**

```
error node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js (144:65) @ location

error ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at Profile (./src/app/profile/page.js:32:20)
```

**Here is the code in question:**

```
'use client'

import Navbar from '@/components/UI/Navbar'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { UserAuth } from '../context/AuthContext'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Modal from '@/components/UI/Modal';

const Profile = () => {

    const [hasData, setHasData] = useState(false)
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    const [data, setData] = useState()

    const { user } = UserAuth()
    const router = useRouter()

    if (!user) {
        if (!user) {
            router.push('/signin')
        }
        return ""
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <main>
                <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold'>Welcome Back</h1>
                    <p className='text-sm font-normal'>View your submitted forms here</p>

                    {!hasData ? (<p className='text-center mt-10'>You have not submitted any forms.</p>) : (
                        <div className="overflow-x-auto px-5 mx-auto mt-10 w-5/6 ">
                            <table className="table">
                                {/* head */}
                                <thead>
                                    <tr className='grid grid-cols-4'>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {/* row 1 */}
                                    <tr className='grid grid-cols-4'>
                                        <td className='flex items-center'>
                                            <div>
                                                <div className="font-bold">Form 1</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td className='col-span-2'>
                                            <div className='rounded-md w-fit bg-yellow-400 px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm'>{data.status}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <th>
                                            <button
                                                className="rounded-md w-fit bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
                                                onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
                                            >
                                                Details
                                            </button>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </main>
            <Modal isVisible={showModal} onClose={() => setShowModal(false)} data={data} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

I've seen a post regarding this error in the past but this is before NextJS 13 was introducted where it is recommended to use 'useRouter' from 'next/navigation' rather than the previous 'next/router'.

**Edit:** Also including the code for 'UserAuth':

```
import { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    signInWithPopup,
    signOut,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword
} from "firebase/auth";

import { auth } from "@/config/firebase";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const googleSignIn = () => {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
    };

    const logOut = () => {
        return signOut(auth);
    };

    const login = (email, password) => {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {

            if (currentUser) {
                currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult => {
                    currentUser.admin = idTokenResult.claims.admin
                })
                localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser))
                setUser(currentUser);
            } else {
                localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
                setUser(null)
            }
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, googleSignIn, logOut, login }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

Any help in tacking this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting to the question description?

Comment: Yes, I've added it now.

Comment: Where are you using the `location` in the above code?

Comment: That's the problem. I'm not using location anywhere in my code so I don't know why I'm getting the error

Comment: Is the code you shared, the whole `src/app/profile/page.js` file?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Can you console.log the output of `useRouter()`?

Comment: Yep. Check it out here: https://imgur.com/a/svdCSM2

Comment: Can you delete your `.next`, `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and do a `npm install` and then verify whether its working?

Comment: Also, can you share the code for `UserAuth` component?

Comment: Yes I've tried that and I'm still getting the error. I think its something to do with it rendering on the server before the client, not too sure. I've edited the post to include the code for 'userAuth'

Comment: Since you have `use client` in `src/app/profile/page.js`, anything imported into that component becomes a client component.

Comment: Do you have a github link I can take a look to see the whole code?

Comment: Yep. https://github.com/Contradicted/clc-form

Comment: If you replace `router.push('/signin')` with `window.location.replace('/signin')`, what happens?

Comment: No I am still getting the error.

Comment: When I wrap the 'check to see if the user is authenticated' inside a useEffect the error goes which leads me to believe its an issue with the server not knowing the path to send to the user since its client rendered hence the location error. The problem with this approach is that I see the protected page slightly before it takes me back to the signin page for example.

Answer (score 1):

Move `router.push` into `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      if (!user) {
        router.push('/signin');
      }
    }
  }, [user]);
```

The client side routing needs to depend on the component is mounted.